# Is there a way to instantly reverse an OK of a question by a new user?

Tags: discussion

I got distracted and OKed a very bad question from a new user.  Mea Culpa.  Is there anything I can do except downvote and vote to close in this situation?  Is there no way to say "Oops, I take it back"?

Comment: What do you mean by "OKed"? You mean you clicked "No action needed" in the review queue?

Comment: Yes, and it was a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any, but you shouldn't worry about it. At most, it might lead to the question being removed from the "posts by new users" queue. You should just deal with it like you would with any bad question you encounter outside of a review queue: you can either downvote, or vote to close, or both, whatever you feel is best. (Or flag if one of those is appropriate.) If you vote to close, it will enter the close-vote review queue.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can do is to go to the post and flag it as low quality or for moderation intervention and mention there what is wrong with the post.

Even if a new post is mistakenly 'OKed' in the review queue, then people will notice it on the page and will deal with it accordingly, so no need to worry.